# What is this H264 container?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, h.264, vlc

I have an H264 video file, when I remove a header that I think is a container, I can play it in VLC or convert with ffmpeg.

This is the Header that appear before a **I frame**:
Note: Ever start with 02** 32 **64 63 and have 0x40 = 64 bytes.
After that start the H264 NAL 00 00 00 01...
[image]

This is the Header that appear before a **P frame**:
Note: Ever start with 02** 33 **64 63 and have 0x40 = 64 bytes.
After that start the H264 NAL 00 00 00 01...
[image]

This is the Header that appear before a **audio frame**:
Note: Ever start with 02** 34 **64 63 and have 0x40 = 64 bytes.
I still don't use it because the device has no audio.
[image]

Maybe if I know what it is I can extract more info or set ffmpeg to convert directly.
These are not a magic number in:

[https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Where did you get these files? Maybe the 'header' is a leftover from some transport or storage protocol.

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, but what protocol? this stream was requested for a device to get it from its storage.

Comment: I'm trying to remove it from the stream, but during tests I saw that the first byte could be 0x00 too :/